# Trying to specify a query param (q) works using SDK but returns 401 unauthorized from cURL

Tags: curl, soundcloud

I am trying to do a search query on the SoundCloud API.

Using their JavaScript SDK, the following works:

```
SC.get('/tracks', { q: 'punk' }, function(tracks) {
  console.log(tracks);
});
```

But if I try to do the same query using cURL:

```
curl -v http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?q=punk&client_id=xxxx
```

It says `<error>401 - Unauthorized</error>`

If I change the order of the query params `http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=xxxx&q=punk` it will disregard the `q` param and respond with the default track listing.

What is the proper way to query the tracks endpoint from cURL?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing incorrect about the URL you're using, so if you're getting a 401 it is because you are using an invalid client id. Please double check that the client id is the same as the one you are using when initializing the JavaScript SDK.

For example, the following works just fine using a client id of one of my test apps:

`curl "https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?q=track&client_id=aeb03ac55f278fc7e579c744144b1d5d`

The order of the parameters in the querystring will have no effect on the response.